# File upload-Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I know this question is answered in stackoverflow.com and I have also got the solution from here. However, its not working in my case.

I have a file upload control which accepts pdf files only. User can upload 4 pdf files one by one i.e. user has to select one file, upload it and then follow the same procedure for next file. Following is the setting in my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
```

I am trying to upload pdf files which are around 300 to 600 KBs. First two files are getting uploaded successfully but for 3rd file the error (?) appears. Sometimes, it's the case for 2nd file also. The things are working fine on Mozilla FireFox but not on Internet Explorer.

Can anybody please help me in this case? Please let me know in case of more details.

Thanks!

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"
 maxRequestLength="2097151" 
                 />

Answer (score 1):

I got the same behavior.

Played a bit with Wireshark with IE8 and Chrome Frame. Discovered that IE request got closed by the server after the upload, but Chrome Frame not. Chrome got a (http) 302 and redirected, but IE got only a (tcp) FIN, ACK. No 500, no 302, no nothing. The connection has just closed by the server.

**Following are the headers used by the browsers, if it can help:**

Google Chrome Frame request headers (working good):

```
POST /imoveis/anuncio/editar/46209/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Origin: http://my.app.domain.com.br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDKMGqhL7VpWUJMqo
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Referer: http://my.app.domain.com.br/imoveis/anuncio/editar/46209/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: my.app.domain.com.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; chromeframe/17.0.963.56) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11
UA-CPU: x86
Content-Length: 595570
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: __utma=1.1002822509.1319114684.1330370473.1330376655.5; __utmz=1.1330370473.4.2.utmcsr=my.app.domain.com.br|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utmb=1.32.9.1330378511998; __utmc=1; csrftoken=276036c343acffb409104f6cb791c6ab; NREUM=s=1330378484891&r=173412&p=0; sessionid=3b1545b33ae14c8bc627a170fba7b6ac; sessionid=73f3659a6dfc0d66a36d0eeaaceebed8
```

Internet Explorer 8.0 request headers (working bad):

```
POST /imoveis/anuncio/editar/46209/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Referer: http://my.app.domain.com.br/imoveis/anuncio/editar/46209/
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dc32924501de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: my.app.domain.com.br
Content-Length: 595617
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: __utma=1.1885672064.1330371076.1330371076.1330376978.2; __utmb=1.16.10.1330376978; __utmz=1.1330371076.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); csrftoken=f46b98f9f51af4e1771f0265c2b5a7b3; NREUM=s=1330378236829&r=190380&p=216226; __utmc=1; sessionid=59a026047075be12b0859a12a1416270
```

I am still looking for a reason...